# ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm currently working on a Mozilla Firefox addon.

I have set up a panel and attached a content script to it. I need to communicate between the content scripts and main.js. I'm using the port api of the addon-sdk for this. However for some reason, I can't even get a simple message through between the two.

I am constantly receiving the following error when I test my addon using cfx: "ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Any idea what's wrong?

popup.js

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
self.port.on("dataToPopup", function (data) { 
$("p.test").text(data);
});
```

The error is thrown for the first line itself.

main.js

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var self = require("sdk/self");

var button = ToggleButton({
    id: "my-button",
    label: "my button",
    icon: {
        "16": "./images/tsfm16px.png"
    },
    onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    contentURL: self.data.url("html/popup.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"), self.data.url("scripts/jquery-ui.js"), self.data.url("scripts/popup.js")],    
    onHide: handleHide
});

function handleChange(state) {
    if (state.checked) {
        panel.show({
            position: button
        });
    console.log("panel opened");    
    }
}

function handleHide() {
    button.state('window', {checked: false});
    console.log("panel closed");
}

panel.on("show", function() {
    panel.port.emit("dataToPopup", "flow");
    console.log("data sent");
});
```

The same error is not being thrown for main.js

Anybody experienced this before?

Comment: Are you having the script file in your HTML? Because I think its not being loaded.

Comment: no. i added it as a content script from main.js

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Content scripts do not have access to `require`. Instead **`self` is already declared**.

Just remove the `require` line from `popup.js` (but not `main.js`).

See [Communicating using "port"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#Accessing_port_in_the_Content_Script).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now. I had no idea it was that insignificant an error. Thanks a again.

Comment: The way to say thanks on StackOverflow is accepting (checkmark) and/or upvoting answers that helped you or even solved your problem ;)

Comment: I tried. Can't vote up. Not enough reputation. I have to wait for 3 minutes to accept the answer.

Comment: No worries... I just wasn't sure you knew already, or not, seeing that your account is new. ;)