# npm modules in Firefox-Addon content scripts

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, npm, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

With [jpm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpm), one now (from Firefox 38 on) has the possibility to use npm modules in Firefox Add-ons, cf. [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Using_third-.party_modules_(jpm)).
This appears to be restricted to the main entry file (`index.js` by default), especially since [`require()` isn't defined in content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412124/referenceerror-require-is-not-defined).

Is there any way of using npm modules in content scripts for Firefox-Addons?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the url of a file via `require.resolve`, so use something like:

`contentScriptFile: [ require.resolve("something/lib/file.js"), require("sdk/self").data.url("content-script.js") ]`

This will use a file from npm in a content script.

If the npm file is a CommonJS file then this becomes more tricky, you might have to read the content of the file, and pass that to the content script (using message passing or the `contentScriptOptions`) to have it evaluated with requireJS or something.

Comment: Modules which use C cannot be used no?

Comment: I'm trying this out, and it looks like the code can't interact with the content - I can step into the code, but it can't access the document of my panel.