# Node.js + AngularJs = Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a problem with node.js and angularJs, when i want to run my project in 
the browser i have this issue :

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

I am using gulp to run the project and browserify to accommodate it on browser.

Comment: We cannot guess the line with the error. Please show the code which is generating this behavior.

Comment: sounds like you may be needing to include requirejs

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412124/referenceerror-require-is-not-defined